# How to push a master branch to another address that already has a git repository?

Tags: git, repository

I have two *bare* repositories:

- A old one, with the live website that should be updated - located under `private/repos/live_site.git`; and the live site files are under `www/www`
- A new one, with the new website that should go live - located under `private/repos/new_site.git`; and the new website files are under `www/new/`

I need to pass all data from `www/new/` to `www/www`

Is there a way to do it using git, in a less "harder way"*.

*By harder way I mean:

**1)** remove all that is inside `www/www`;

**2)** ssh to the remote server;

**3)** clone new_site.git into `www/www`;

If more details are necessary, please, let me know.

Comment: Why is step 2 (ssh) happening after step 1 (removing `www/www`)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit overcomplicated to me. Why don't you try to just point your server to a new repo having all new web site? If this is not an option for whatever reason, then you can merge two histories:

have a local cloned repo of live. Connect to the remote new, fetch all the info. then you have a choice of either merging the histories or just switching one of the brances of live (master) to the new/master

`git checkout master` `# make sure there is no uncommitted stuff to avoid loosing some work`

```
git reset --hard new/master
```

The whole working directory will change to reflect the state of the new/master
you can move all files now from www/new folder to www/www folder. Commit the move and force push it to the live remote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily move around the folders for everything to work, unless there are some configuration files inside which need to be accordingly modified.

```
mv www/www www/old
mv www/new www/www
```